# How to avoid C++ code bloat issued by template instantiation and symbol table?

Tags: c++11, templates, gcc, bare-metal

I'd started a bare-metal (Cortex-M) project some years ago. At project setup we decided to use gcc toolchain with C++11 / C++14 etc. enabled and even for using C++ exceptions and rtti.

We are currently using [gcc 4.9 from launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.9/4.9-2015-q3-update) (having some issue which prevent us currently to update to a more recent gcc version).

For example, I'd wrote a base class and a derived class like this (see also running example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a0d621073175d43)):

```
class OutStream {
public:
    explicit OutStream() {}
    virtual ~OutStream() {}
    OutStream& operator << (const char* s) {
        write(s, strlen(s));
        return *this;
    }
    virtual void write(const void* buffer, size_t size) = 0;    
};

class FixedMemoryStream: public OutStream {
public:
    explicit FixedMemoryStream(void* memBuffer, size_t memBufferSize): memBuffer(memBuffer), memBufferSize(memBufferSize) {}
    virtual ~FixedMemoryStream()       {}
    const void*  getBuffer() const     { return memBuffer; }
    size_t       getBufferSize() const { return memBufferSize; }
    const char*  getText() const       { return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(memBuffer); }  ///< returns content as zero terminated C-string    
    size_t       getSize() const       { return index; }                                     ///< number of bytes really written to the buffer (max = buffersize-1)
    bool         isOverflow() const    { return overflow; }
    virtual void write(const void* buffer, size_t size) override { /* ... */ }
private:
    void*  memBuffer = nullptr;   ///< buffer
    size_t memBufferSize = 0;     ///< buffer size
    size_t index = 0;             ///< current write index
    bool   overflow = false;      ///< flag if we are overflown
};
```

So that the customers of my class are now able to use e.g.:

```
char buffer[10];
FixedMemoryStream ms1(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
ms1 << "Hello World";
```

Now I'd want to make the usage of the class a bit more comfortable and introduced the following template:

```
template<size_t bufferSize> class FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer: public FixedMemoryStream {
public:
    explicit FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer(): FixedMemoryStream(buffer, bufferSize) {}
private:
    uint8_t buffer[bufferSize];
};
```

And from now, my customers can write:

```
FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer<10> ms2;
ms2 << "Hello World";
```

But from now, I'd observed increasing size of my executable binary. It seems that gcc added symbol information for each different template instantiation of `FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer` (because we are using rtti for some reason).

Might there be a way to get rid of symbol information only for some specific classes / templates / template instantiations?

It's ok to get a non portable gcc only solution for this.

For some reason we decided to prefer templates instead of preprocessor macros, I want to avoid a preprocessor solution.

Comment: What if you remove the virtual functions? Only polymorphic objects can use RTTI.

Comment: The virtual functions are definitively needed, because I have some other classes which are derived from `OutStream` (e.g. UartStream, TcpStream et cetera).

Comment: There's only a need if you use these derived classes polymorphically (i.e. through expressions of the base class' type).

Comment: `operator <<` is a poor interface to use in embedded system. It requires an instance per type to "stream", so you end up with many similar prologue/epilogue in your binary. You should try to use printf like solution instead (since va_list, as bad as they seems are quite optimal in binary size).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, keep in mind that compiler also generates separate v-table (as well as RTTI information) for every FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer<> type instance, as well as every class in the inheritance chain.

In order to resolve the problem I'd recommend using containment instead of inheritance with some conversion function and/or operator inside:

```
    template<size_t bufferSize> 
    class FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer
    {
         uint8_t buffer[bufferSize];
         FixedMemoryStream m_stream;
    public:
        explicit FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer() : m_stream(m_buffer, bufferSize) {}
        operator FixedMemoryStream&() { return m_stream; }
        FixedMemoryStream& toStream() { return m_stream; }
   };
```

Comment: Interesting approach. As `FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer` is not longer polymorphic, the compiler has a real chance to get rid of the symbol information. But unfortunately, I have to call `toStream()` method like `ms.toStream() << "Hallo World";` from now, because the cast operator won't work implicitly for this case.

Comment: @Joe, but what prevents you from defining your own "operator<<" which redirects the request to the right stream? In fact, I suppose you'll have to redefine the whole stream interface (functions, such as flush()) in order to make it behave like a real stream. Yes, it may be a lot of extra work, but it solves your problem of unnecessary RTTI and v-table introductions. As the classics say: "There is no easy way out!"

Comment: Yep, I have to copy an amount of `operator<<` for all the data types which are supported by my `OutStream` for now and for future. This definitively violates against [Dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @Joe I disagree. You forget about templates. Single template operator<< may forward everything to your real stream.
template <typename T>
FixedMemoryStream& operator<<(T&& val) {
    return m_stream << std::forward<T>(val);
}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way to bring the necessary symbols almost down to `0`: using the standard library. Your `OutStream` class is a simplified version of `std::basic_ostream`. Your `OutStream::write` is really just `std::basic_ostream::write` and so on. Take a look at it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream). Overflow is handled really closely, though, for completeness' sake, it also deals with `underflow` i.e. the need for data retrieval; you may leave it as undefined (it's `virtual` too).

Similarly, your `FixedMemoryStream` is [`std::basic_streambuf<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) with a fixed-size (a `std::array<T>`) get/put area.

So, just make your classes inherit from the standard ones and you'll cut off on binary size since you're reusing already declared symbols.

---

Now, regarding `template<size_t bufferSize> class FixedMemoryStreamWithBuffer`. This class is very similar to `std::array<std::uint8_t, bufferSize>` as for the way memory is specified and acquired. You *can't* optimize much about that: each instantiation is a **different** type with all what that implies. The compiler cannot "merge" or do anything magic about them: each instantiation must have its own type.
So either fall back on `std::vector` or have some fixed-size specialized chunks, like 32, 128 etc. and for any values in between would choose the right one; this can be achieved entirely at compile-time, so no runtime cost.

Comment: That would replace code from the OP's program by code from the standard library

Comment: My `OutStream` and derived class & template is just an example to describe the problem. I have some other cases which classes have no similar one's in the standard library. However for the `OutStream` case, I need to strictly don't use `stdio` because it blasts up my codesize for a quite huge amount of bytes and also allocates some memory from heap which is mostly expensive on bare-metal.

Comment: @Joe: whether your code uses (or may use) `iostream`, the second part of my answer still holds. BTW, you might try taking RTTI out of the equation and so turn  `-nortti` on. RTTI and exceptions are heavy on symbols and memory.

Comment: You're changing Bob for Alice here. If he's not using iostream, changing his class to use it implies compiling iostream into his binary. And in this case, it's most likely Alice is fatter than Bob.